# Randomly select a pair of elements from a two dimensional array and place them in a sentence in python

Tags: python, arrays, random

```
import random

quizwords = [["hot", "cold"],["summer","winter"],["hard","soft"],["dry","wet"],["simple","complex"],["light","darkness"],["weak","strong"],["male","female"],["sad","happy"],["win","lose"],["small","big"],["ignore","pay attention"],["sell","buy"],["succeed","fail"],["reject","accept"],["prevent","allow"],["exclude","include"]]

c = 0
random.shuffle(quizwords)
for i in quizwords:
    print(i[0][0],"is to",i[0][1],"as",i[1][0],"is to...")
    ans = input()
```

This is my code so far and I believe it would for example output 'e is to c as s is to...'
im trying to have it instead say 'exclude is to include as reject is to...(answer: accept)'

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

quizwords = [["hot", "cold"],["summer","winter"],["hard","soft"],["dry","wet"],["simple","complex"],["light","darkness"],["weak","strong"],["male","female"],["sad","happy"],["win","lose"],["small","big"],["ignore","pay attention"],["sell","buy"],["succeed","fail"],["reject","accept"],["prevent","allow"],["exclude","include"]]

c = 0
random.shuffle(quizwords)
for i in range(len(quizwords) - 1)[::2]:
    first_pair = quizwords[i]
    second_pair = quizwords[i+1]
    print(f'{first_pair[0]} is to {first_pair[1]} as {second_pair[0]} is to...')
    ans = input()
```

Since you're already iterating through items in the list in the for-loop, doing two levels of indexing was pulling the first letter of each word.